# I can't get a div next to another

Tags: html, css

I want to class="contactvlak" to get next to class="middentextvak", I've tried a lot of things like changing positions etc. but it doesn't seem to work at all. I'm sorry if this sounds like a really stupid question.

```
<div class="midden">
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
    <div class="middentextvak">
        <h1>Welkom bij autorijschool NRV! </h1>
        <p>In Veldhoven en omgevingen verzorgen wij uw complete rijopleiding in onze volkswagen.
            <br>Een rijopleiding met oog voor detail. U en uw behoefte staan hierbij steeds centraal.
            <br>Onze ervaren instructeur geeft u een moderne rijopleiding geheel afgestemd op uw aanvangsniveau. Zo ben u altijd verzekerd van het zo mogelijk behalen van uw rijbewijs tegen een zo laag mogelijke prijs.
            <br>
            <br>
            Klik <a href="http://www.rijschoolgegevens.nl/index.asp?pageid=2&examenplaats=75&rijschoolid=5285&fromsearch=1">hier</a> voor de meest recente slagingspercentage.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contactvlak"></div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
.midden
{
    clear:both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

}
.middentextvak
{

    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 43%;
    height: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin-top: 7%;

}

.contactvlak
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;

}

.middentextvak h1
{
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-family:Arial;
    color: #0671ca;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.middentextvak p
{
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-family:Arial;
    margin-top: -2%;
}
.logo
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:70%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity:0.5;
    clear: both;
}
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5LmF/9/

Edit: Sorry posted the wrong fiddle!

Comment: Your demo includes neither CSS nor HTML for the `.contactvlak` element(s).

Comment: It also includes no `contactvlak` element at all.

Comment: Sorry all! It seems I forgot to save D'oh! 1 minute!

Comment: Ok, the right one is up now! sorry!

Comment: `float: left`/`float: right`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for Reply, I tried that but then the middentextvlak isn't at the center anymore.

Comment: Didn't see you mention that was required.

Comment: You'll want to use `position` on a parent, since `position` requires a parent to have `position` to be able to work off of. By giving the parent `position: relative` (more or less regular positioning flow context), and using `position: absolute` on the inner element, it will be positioned based on the parent's display context (including dimensions). You might also want to include a `z-index`, which gives it a "layer" position (like cards in a deck) so it "lays" on top of other elements (or underneath, depending on the context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.midden`, and `position:absolute` and `top:0` to `.contactvlak`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H5LmF/10/)**

Comment: @user3750069 - Sure, just add `right:0` to `.contactvlak`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H5LmF/10/

Comment: If you want to get the result to the right side, use `float: right` css property

Answer (score 0):

The classes `middentextvak`  and `contactvlak` are the children of class `midden`. Right?

So add `display: inline; position: relative` properties to the `midden` class and you will get the two divs side by side.

Comment: `display: inline` is not needed.